# How create my on ISO DVD?

Tags: iso

I have installed ubuntu on my computer, I have almost fixed all the problems it presented and now it works very well, although there are still things to be adjusted, but I would like to take an iso of my system to be able to install on other computers of the same trademarl and model

How can I create my own ISO on a DVD and include the hash?

Thank you

Comment: it's my first question, if it's wrong, do not judge me wrong, it's my first time here, better tell me the correct way to do it, through a comment

Comment: I found several answers but not very complete, collect notes of what I read but I lack experience and I did not understand well Do you know where I can read about this topic at the beginner level?

Comment: ho...!!! jejeje sorry, I did not see it well, I'm on my phone and it did not show me the link
Thanks

Comment: @Parto I do not want to make a clone of my disk, the question is not related to my question, I want to make an iso to install systems

Comment: Do you have more answers on this topic or a guide?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone your computer you can use systemback to make an iso. Just type this into the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback`

Once you have systemback click on live system create and it will make an iso for you.

But if you want to get a fresh copy of ubuntu you can download an iso here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download
Since you mentioned that you already are running ubuntu use startup disk creator to make a live usb or dvd. Just search it in dash(top left corner button) and follow the instructions that it gives.

Comment: Hi @kingofrubik, i want create a new ISO based on my existent linux
a iso works to make new installations, no clone partitions, no clone hard disk, There are many issues such as the one I was sent to create clones of partitions and hard drives, but it's not what I want, I want my current linux with which I work, package it in an iso that I can use to reinstall in any PC, like if you installed a normal ubuntu

Comment: but your council is also good, surely reading about what you tell me leads me to learn how to create a new iso as if I were doing linux from scratch